# byte array to blob data type in mule using ojdbc8 jar

Tags: java, oracle11g, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I am trying to read an image/pdf from file connector and store this in oracle database having column with BLOB data type. This is working when I am using ojdbc6.jar. Its not working with ojdbc8.jar.

after collecting file I added file to byte array transformer and then database insert was working using ojdbc6.

Can you provide any suggestions for this?

The code I am able to run using ojdbc6 is

```
<flow name="blob-testFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\xyxyz\Desktop\filetoblobsdkj" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:file-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="File to Byte Array"/>
    <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO filetoblob(id,data)
        VALUES(11,#[payload])]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: What does "Its not working with ojdbc8.jar" mean? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error message? Does the JDBC library work in other situations and is it only failing for blobs? Please help us by showing what you have done to attempt to debug this.

Comment: In mule application, when we use oracle connection we need to add oracle dependency. That I have added ojdbc version 6 dependency -- here I was able to run the application properly. When I use  ojdbc version 8 I got the error **invalid column type** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution after struggle. I just have to modify insert query from

```
INSERT INTO filetoblob(id,data)
VALUES(11,#[payload])
```

to

```
INSERT INTO filetoblob
VALUES(11,#[payload])
```